# Insert event handler's name to json2html's template as childern

Tags: javascript, json, json2html

I'm using [json2Html](https://json2html.com/).

```
  var template = {
            "tag": "tr",
            "children": [
              {
                "tag": "td",
                // "html": "<input type='radio' name='TenantID' value='${TenantID}' onclick='onTenantClick(event)'/>" // This works                
                "children": [
                {                          
                "tag": "input",
                "type": "radio",
                "name": "TenantID",
                "value": "${TenantID}",
                "onclick": "onTenantClick(event)"
                }
                ]                
              },
          ]
};
```

The "html" part works. If I add the radio element as a child (children), I get `TypeError: e.data.action.call is not a function` for the onclick event handler.

The doc's examples  (https://json2html.com/examples/) show like this :

```
"onclick":function(){
                        $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
```

But I want to insert the function name which is in another .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [json2html.com](https://json2html.com/docs/#main-attributes-events) docs any on event must be a function.  So if you want to call another function you'll need to wrap in like so

```
var template = {
            "<>": "tr",
            "html": [
              {
                "<>": "td",               
                "html": [
                {                          
                "tag": "input",
                "type": "radio",
                "name": "TenantID",
                "value": "${TenantID}",
                "onclick": function(e) { onTenantClick(e.event); }
                }
                ]                
              },
          ]
};
```

Note that "tag" has been deprecated and replaced with "<>" and "children" deprecated and replaced with "html"